Displaying data in one row for all attributes in Row shelf
I need help in displaying one row for each account name. Apart from the Account name, all attributes in the row shelf are calculated fields that say Yes or No based on the Amount in the Column shelf. The amount is getting split based on the attributes on the column shelf, which I don't want. I want to see aggregated values for each Account name.
I have attached the screenshot for reference.


Drag the most granular field to the far left of the rows shelf, something like [item id], it will force all the rows to populate at that level of detail and won't aggregate like answers.
